# How to stack sequences of different lengths into a batch in pytorch and how to ignore the padding afterwards

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, padding

I am trying to build a neural network with pytorch. Part of its input is a set of sequences  that have different lengths. Simplified example (they are ratings):

```
sample 1: [4, 4.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
sample 2: [3, 3.5, 5]
...
sample 32: [2.5, 5, 3.5, 4, 5.0, 3.5]
```

In reality, each sample has a shape of (x, 128) where 128 is fixed (features multiplied by rating) and x is variable length.

When I try to simply return each sequence as that in Dataset's `__getitem__(self, item)` I get an error `RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size`.

I am assuming there needs to be some padding so that we can end up with fixed size tensors for a batch that can be passed to a `nn.Module`'s `forward()`. But:

1. How do I perform such a padding?
2. How do I make the `forward()` ignore the padding?

For the network part, what I need to is to run each element of the sequence through the same `nn.Sequencial()` sub-network whilst somehow "accumulating" the gradients/losses. I imagine that a simple python for-loop until a padded element would be innefficient. Is there a smarter way to do this e.g. by including the lengths of each sample? I ve seen similar stuff but they were "built-in" for an LSTM module, not a feedforward one, if I recall correctly.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible in PyTorch [see here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-the-variable-length-input-in-rnn-scenario/345).

Comment: My current best guess for 1. is to use a custom `collate_fn` method in DataLoaders where I would do the padding + adding a lengths tensor to avoid the error.

Comment: For 2. it looks like I may have to resort to doing separate passes for each sample in a batch, then concat the result and continue normally for the rest (upper) layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can pad each tensor before fusing it into batches

```
import torch

padded_value = -1
max_size = 6

x = [torch.tensor([4, 4.5, 3, 3.5, 4]),
     torch.tensor([3, 3.5, 5]),
     torch.tensor([2.5, 5, 3.5, 4, 5.0, 3.5])]

padded = [torch.cat([item,torch.tensor([padded_value]).expand(
         max_size- len(item))]) for item in x]

batches = torch.cat([item[None] for item in padded])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
test_batch= [torch.randn(3, 24), torch.randn(4, 24), torch.randn(3, 24), torch.randn(5, 24)]

# Find the maximum sequence length in the batch
max_seq_len = max([x.size(0) for x in test_batch])

# Pad the sequences to have the same length within the batch
padded_batch_data = [nn.functional.pad(x, (0, 0, 0, max_seq_len - x.size(0))) for x in test_batch]

# Stack the padded sequences into a single tensor
data_batch_padded = torch.stack(padded_batch_data, dim=0)
print(f"This is the shape of the batched data filled with zeros:{data_batch_padded.shape}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).